# Maximum summed sub sequences with no two numbers sharing the same digit

Tags: array

Suppose there are 5 positive integers in an array or list as 14, 12, 23, 45, 39.

14 and 12 cannot be taken in the subset as 1 is common in both. Similarly {12, 23}, {23, 39}, {14, 45} cannot be included in the same subset.

So the subset which forms the maximum sum is {12, 45, 39}. The maximum sum such formed is 96.

the result should be the maximum sum of such combination.

Sample TestCase 1
Input
3,5,7,2
Output
17

Sample Test Case 2
Input
121,23,3,333,4
Output
458

Sample Test Case 3
Input
32,42,52,62,72,82,92
Output
92

Explanation

Test Case 1: {3, 5, 7, 2} = 17

Test Case 2: {121, 333, 4} = 458

Test Case 3: {92} = 92

Comment: thanks for the information, i've tagged it appropriately.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: added few more test cases.

Comment: Is this challenge from another programming contest site?

Comment: Why did you remove the winning criterion? Doing so makes the challenge off-topic.

Comment: ...plus there are already nine answers using code-golf as a winning criteria.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
æʒ€ÙJDÙQ}OZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJTkx41rTk808vl8MzAWv@o//@jDY0MdRSMjY11FExiAQ)

**Explanation**

```
æʒ      }    # filter the powerset of the input, keep only elements
  €Ù         # where each number with duplicate digits removed
    JDÙQ     # have different digits from the other numbers
         O   # sum each
          Z  # take max
```

Comment: Test Case 2: {121, 333, 4} = 458

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Ah OK. Same digits in a number is okay. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 77 bytes

```
Max[Tr/@Select[(s=Subsets)@#,!Or@@IntersectingQ@@@s[IntegerDigits/@#,{2}]&]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYuxCsIwFEV3/0KEovCg5KW17VB4g4uDqNQtZIglxIDtkEQQSr89posodzvn3EGFhx5UsL2Kpo0n9RY3l1Onn7oPYuvb7nX3OvgdbWB9dkTHMWjnk7SjuRKRFwsx2h2sscHnqZtwlpmUWbw4OwYyYmIFMATkUJTAm1muvoZDCRXgL2LIljSNp8NfjFAglAh7hAqhRmjSM8YP)

Comment: thanks for the solution, could you please explain, as I have limited knowledge of Wolfram Langauge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>137</s> <s>112</s> <s>105</s> <s>119</s> 116 bytes

```python
lambda a,s='':a and max([x+f(a[1:],y)for x,y in(0,s),(a[0],s+`set(`a[0]`)`)if max(map(y.count,'1234567890'))<2])or 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUxLDoIwFNx7irejDRNDX4uAkZMgCfXTSCKFCCZweqwujGY28x@W6dZ7Xl15XO@2O10sWYxlFO0D8Rfq7CyqOXbCVmpfY5Guf9CMhVovEowSIUhqjHEzXifRvEUjG9m6z7Kzg1i25/7pJ0SKtUl3WV4kkZQHrmV4Stbh0fqJnKiUASkGsQaZFKSLWm6@qUaKDPxrKVYI5QCtYf7KDMNIGTtGxsgZRViuLw)

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 116 bytes

```python
lambda a,s='':a and max(x+f(a[1:],y)for x in(0,a[0])if max(map((y:=s+str(set(str(x)*x))).count,'1234567890'))<2)or 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNboMwEITvfQrf2G1GFV6b8KPyJISD09QqUjEIXMk8PSU5RIrmMKuZb2fe4s8UTDUvu28v@68brzenHNY2y5rjCDc1ukTp5Ml1uumxsZ8WldQQKIfr8p4H/0BGNxNtTbue1rjQ@h3p7onfEzN/fE1/ISLTYmxxLqs6z5g/hY@pfJ@XIUTy1GkLpQVKDJQtoEzdM789a4MCJeQl06Jx4IeMgX3FBVZQCM6CUlAJ6vvv/g8)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, added more test cases.

Comment: Failing the second test case. Sample Test Case 2 Input 121,23,3,333,4 Output 458

Comment: Needs more work I think since `print f([121,23,3,333,4])` in the TIO returns 27, not 458.

Comment: @biziden Fixed.

Comment: @KjetilS. Fixed

Comment: thanks for the solution, although it's giving syntax error on Python 3.7

Comment: @biziden The top one is for Python 2 (probably 2.7), the bottom one uses 3.8 features, neither will work in 3.7. Furthermore note that this stack is not the place to get a piece of code to do the task at hand, in most cases the code would not be what you want to use in any real scenario.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, I am new here and didn't know it, I am happy to see so many new programming languages, which I was not aware of, do we also provide pseudo-code over here.

Comment: Pseudo-code cannot usually compete (unless the challenge warrants it, which is unlikely). Note that the vast majority of challenges have a winning criteria of [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Nick Kennedy (use the implicit `make_digits` of `Q` to get rid of `D`)

```
ŒPQ€FQƑƊƇ§Ṁ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of positive integers which yields the maximal sum of those subsets which repeat no decimal digits between elements.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIDAR01r3AKPTTzWdaz90PKHOxv@//8fbWhkqKNgZKyjAELGQMIkFgA)**

#### How?

```
ŒPQ€FQƑƊƇ§Ṁ - Link: list of positive integers
ŒP          - power set
        Ƈ   - filter keep those for which:
       Ɗ    -   last three links as a monad:
  Q€        -     de-duplicate each
    F       -     flatten
      Ƒ     -     is invariant under:
     Q      -       de-duplication
         §  - sum each
          Ṁ - maximum
```

Comment: You can drop the D: `ŒPQ€FQƑƊƇ§Ṁ` for 11

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot that `Q` performs a call to `iterable` with `make_digits=True`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```javascript
f=([n,...a],s=m=0,p='')=>n?f(a,s,p,p.match(`[${n}]`)||f(a,s+n,p+n)):m=m>s?m:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwFET3fkUXQhM6RnPbWitEP6QUDLX1gUmDETfqt9cHClpnlnM4zF6fta@OO3ca2XZdd12jWGEhhNAlvDJqAqfCkKuFXTZMw8PBCaNP1ZatiuHF3soVv15fU2ThIsv53Ciz8Esz913VWt8eanFoN6xhhUwgCRQjSRHnwSsl58F4HOTTQQ@OkSIDBd95wzLrw5Lk0/to/LD/wEk6@1MTEkJKmBIywoyQ0@cHdXc)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                    // f is a recursive function taking:
  [n, ...a],             //   n = next value from a[]; a[] = remaining values
  s =                    //   s = current sum
  m = 0,                 //   m = maximum sum, which is eventually returned
  p = ''                 //   p = all previous digits, as a string
) =>                     //
  n ?                    // if n is defined:
    f(                   //   do a recursive call ...
      a, s, p,           //     ... with all parameters unchanged
      p.match(`[${n}]`)  //     tests whether p contains any digit of n
      ||                 //     if it doesn't:
        f(               //       do another recursive call with:
          a,             //         a[] unchanged
          s + n,         //         n added to s (as an integer)
          p + n          //         n appended to p (as a string)
        )                //       end of inner recursive call
    )                    //   end of outer recursive call
  :                      // else:
    m = m > s ? m : s    //   this is a leaf node: update m to max(m, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>81</s> 76 bytes

```
_?[]=0
n?(a:b)|any(`elem`n)$show a=n?b|True=max(n?b)$a+(n++show a)?b
g=(""?)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P94@OtbWgCvPXiPRKkmzJjGvUiMhNSc1NyFPU6U4I79cIdE2zz6pJqSoNNU2N7FCA8jRVEnU1sjT1oZIa9oncaXbaigp2Wv@z03MzFOwVSgoyswrUVBRSFeINjQy1DEy1gFCY2Mdk9j/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
{⊇.dᵐc≠∧}ᶠ+ᵒt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pRV7teysOtE5IfdS541LG89uG2BdoPt04q@f8/2tDIUMfIWAcIjY11TGL/RwEA)

#### Explanation

```
{     }ᶠ         Find all…
 ⊇.                subsets of the input…
   dᵐ              …where each number with duplicate digits removed…
     c≠∧           …has different digits from the others
          +ᵒ     Order by sum
            t    Tail (last element)
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed at the cost of 2 bytes, thanks.

Comment: You seem to output the list instead of the sum.

Comment: might not work for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 82 bytes

```perl
max(map{my$n=2*$_;my@t=grep{($n/=2)%2}@_;"@t"!~/(\d).* .*\1/?sum(@t):0}0..2**@_-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZPRToMwFIbveYpKMGnJkY0DbAOC8gB6N@@WLFM7bUIZ0pJJCL46FuZufABsr/r/pz0nX/5WvC6iQbYk11zp7PNMyb8syw/BR8AAwgiC@CrHqxlHCCCCNeAf2V/PSQH9kYHZgSFxlcNoMyMFhBAhQlghrBE2CLFBEuOMFFhqNYqTrUlkkjydak7GcKrsPkyt84coOJ3SyjprLJctdUQJzqnRLFNVIV75ZMMSMP2tILkoJ0/bYIMpvxhC0SM1FrvcTq1@avwoxsbPWhTEfAjVSCIPX8ZVzQs5doM5UHmoOtk6ZYaus09lm@vsveZVR51ykSG7xT7fp3au7ZvvBd29Mc8lnrvzFw/mNTM9S5b90vPQdfP9nc@GfvgB)

With spaces:

```perl
sub f {
    max(
      map {
        my $n = 2 * $_;
        my @t = grep {($n/=2)%2} @_;
        "@t"!~/(\d).* .*\1/ ? sum(@t) : 0
      }
      0 .. 2**@_-1
    )
}
```

Loops through all possible 2^n subarrays of the input array where each element either participates or not. Then for valid subarrays, those not matching the regex which finds common digits in other elements, use the sum of them and return the max of those valid sums.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,r=[],S=set:l and max([f(l[1:],r+l[:1]),f(l[1:],r)][S(`l[0]`)&S(`r`)>S():])or sum(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETvfsWeJIt7MGlrbaD@RI9LoJVaFNK0pBX06@NWQdgHM8MszPxe71MwKQ2178Zr34GnWLOjpl5uq/XQhR7G7qV4UJ61dRQPnq12SP8AHTeq9Xx0Le5FxRYvjULrcIqwPEcVMQ0iPTwCsM4JtCEwGUFeEGSVI2AxokuJN6eN/hW2y7bityNfuVAIJ6EUzkJlnN0BzPERViWrENMH)

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 95 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,r=[]:l and max([f(k:=l[1:],r+l[:1]),f(k,r)][bool({*str(l[0])}&{*str(r)}):])or sum(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvLCoMwEEX3/YpZlaSdReOjasAvGbJQRCodjUQLLcVvT8cKc@Cey535sz78lJZziLGvuRnbrgHGUJOzDM3Uwdi8FfXqaWsmYx2GK5M1TqN0GLSj1ntW38uyBsV0c3o7HxL0pq3TPsDyGsViL5FhmIBMhmAShCRFyHKEtHIIJCK5kHo3k5hjsF@6D/8b@cqEXLgLhVAKVeLsCWAOw7SqXrHW8Qc)